# assign value to dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

i have wriiten javascriot for two levels of dropdown on selecting value in first i get values in second dropdown. now what is happening the value that is there in the array is getting assigned to the second dropdown. i want to assign urls as values to the second dropdown and redirect them to those dropdowns.in my below example if i select apparel then i get men and women in second dropdown so if i select men in second dropdown it should go to xyz.com.... so for each option in second dropdown i want it to be redirected to a specific url how can i do it?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var categories = [];categories["startList"] = ["Apparel","Books"]
categories["Apparel"] = ["Men","Women"];
categories["Books"] = ["Biography","Fiction","Nonfiction"];


var nLists = 2; // number of lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
document.forms[0]['List'+i].length = 1;
document.forms[0]['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
var nCat = categories[currCat];
//var nurl= url[currCat]
for (each in nCat)  {
var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
nOption.appendChild(nData); 
currList.appendChild(nOption); 
} 
}

function getValue(isValue) {
alert(isValue);
}

function init() {
fillSelect('startList',document.forms[0]['List1'])
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);    

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="">
<select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
<option selected>Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<!--<select name='List2' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])">
<option selected>Make a selection</option>
</select>-->
&nbsp;
<select name='List2' onchange="getValue(this.value)">
<option selected >Make a selection</option>
</select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean you want to populate the `dropdown` with an array data?

Comment: yes with urls array data

Answer (score 0):

First you need to modify your source array as JSON format like this :

```
var categories = [];categories["startList"] = [{"text":"Apparel","url":"Apparel"},{"text":"Books","url":"Books"}]
categories["Apparel"] = [{"text":"Men","url":"xyz.com"},{"text":"Women","url":"abc.com"}];
categories["Books"] = [{"text":"Biography","url":"Biography.com"},{"text":"Fiction","url":"Fiction.com"},{"text":"Nonfiction","url":"Nonfiction.com"}];
```

Now, In function we can use it as key value pair :

```
var nLists = 2; // number of lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
document.forms[0]['List'+i].length = 1;
document.forms[0]['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
var nCat = categories[currCat];
//var nurl= url[currCat]
for (each in nCat)  {
var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]["text"]); 
nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]["url"]); 
nOption.appendChild(nData); 
currList.appendChild(nOption); 
} 
}

function getValue(isValue) {
//alert(isValue);
location.replace("http://" + isValue);
}
```

That's it !!!